# UIImagePickerController won't stop location services

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimagepickercontroller, cllocationmanager

Basically what I am trying to accomplish is an augmented reality application.  I have a map view and the augmented reality view.
When the user only looks at the map view and then returns to the previous page in the UINavigation stack all location services are stopped and the arrow toolbar notification dissapears.  It is when the user leaves the map view and the UIImagePickerController is presented modally the location services notification will remain even after the user presses the button that is responsible for stopping all location services and popping the current view.
I know it is not my CLLocationManager causing the problem because as I said the error doesn't occur when the UIImagePicker is never placed on the screen.  My thoughts are that the location services used for geolocating or whatever the camera uses them for is not stopping even though i dimiss the modal view before popping the current view.
For the life of me I can't figure out why they arent stopping, if anyone might know why it would be a huge help.

Here is the code that I have right now in the method that is called to prepare for popping the view from the UINavigation stack

```
[_locationManager setDelegate:nil];
[_locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
[_locationManager stopUpdatingHeading];
[[UIAccelerometer sharedAccelerometer] setDelegate:nil];
if (_imagePickerOn){
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];   
    _imagePickerOn = FALSE;
}
```

--EDIT--
Heres the method where I present the image picker, very basic:

```
- (IBAction) cameraButtonPressed{
_imagePickerOn = TRUE;
[self presentModalViewController:_imagePicker animated:NO];
}
```

Comment: Can you post the method where you present the `UIImagePickerController` object?

Comment: There you go i added it to the original question, that method only gets called when the user wants to leave the map view and go to the augmented reality view and its only after that button is pressed that the problem occurs.  I initialize the imagepicker in the viewDidLoad method

Comment: It is not clear whether the button is the part of the map view or the image picker view? The original code you posted was called on button tap, right?

Comment: The button that calls the presentmodalview is on the UIView that holds the map view.  The original block of code I posted is called when either the map view or the image picker view press 'stop'

Answer (score 0):

I assume you’re allocating the image picker controller in advance elsewhere. That’s probably the problem—when its view goes offscreen (as you dismiss it), it’s not getting deallocated, so it’s still in memory and still presumably using its location manager. It’s a bug, but not your bug, so you’re not going to be able to do much about it with your current setup.

A more common pattern is to only allocate things like UIImagePickerController when you’re about to present them and to release them immediately after the call to `-presentModalViewController:animated:`. It can make your UI a little less responsive, especially when allocating complicated view controller (I’m not sure if the image picker controller qualifies as such), but you get the benefit of reduced memory usage and—hopefully—of no longer using location services when you don’t want them.

Comment: Before i posted up this question I actually tried that.  I 'released' it right before going off screen and it still showed the location services notification.  I tried the more common pattern that you suggested, lazily initializing it and releasing it right after its presented and unfortunately still getting the same error, it shows the little arrow still in the top toolbar upon exiting